# How do I make more block for Bootstrap theme?

Tags: theming

My bootstrap theme block region look doesn't have much block section.

How do I make this like the second image? How do I make more block.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to create custom theme?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "Implementing a functionality or a layout seen in a site, for which just a description of the feature, a screenshot, or a site URL is provided" is on a [list of things you are not allowed to ask here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Have a look at [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) and [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds).